# How do I identify two different spaces between three words in an input from the user in java?

Tags: java, string, input, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your full name:");    


        String input = s.nextLine();

        int space1 = input.indexOf(' '); 

        String fname = input.substring(0,space1);
        System.out.println(fname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method for Strings.

```
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
```